# Minecraft bukkit api plugin crash while enabling

Tags: bukkit

I am new to Bukkit API and I learned java not too long ago. I was working on a minigame plugin.

While Eclipse gives me no errors, it seems to come from within my main class. Minecraft does start up but the console logs that the plugin couldn't start up and when I do a command it is repeated back.

Here's my Main class

```java
package me.jobisingh;

import java.util.HashSet;

import com.sk89q.worldedit.WorldEdit;
import com.sk89q.worldedit.WorldEditOperation;
import com.sk89q.worldedit.bukkit.WorldEditAPI;
import com.sk89q.worldedit.bukkit.WorldEditPlugin;
import com.sk89q.worldedit.bukkit.selections.CuboidSelection;
import com.sk89q.worldedit.bukkit.selections.Selection;
import com.sk89q.worldguard.bukkit.WorldGuardPlugin;
import com.sk89q.worldguard.bukkit.commands.WorldGuardCommands;
import com.sk89q.worldguard.bukkit.listener.WorldGuardBlockListener;
import com.sk89q.worldguard.bukkit.listener.WorldGuardCommandBookListener;

import org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.World;
import org.bukkit.block.Block;

// Color Code Here §

import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.Action;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import me.jobisingh.handlers.Game;

public class MainClass extends JavaPlugin {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        new ListenerClass(this);
        new Game();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {

    }

    private WorldGuardPlugin getWorldGuard() {
        Plugin plugin = getServer().getPluginManager().getPlugin("WorldGuard");

        // WorldGuard may not be loaded
        if (plugin == null || !(plugin instanceof WorldGuardPlugin)) {
            return null; // Maybe you want throw an exception instead
        }

        return (WorldGuardPlugin) plugin;
    }

    public WorldEditPlugin getWorldEdit() {

        Plugin p = Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().getPlugin("WorldEdit");
        if(p instanceof WorldEditPlugin) return (WorldEditPlugin) p;
        else return null;
    }



    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("setteam1spawn") && sender instanceof Player) {

            Player player = (Player) sender;

            Block getBlock = player.getTargetBlock((HashSet<Byte>)null, 100);

            int x = getBlock.getX();
            int y = getBlock.getY();
            int z = getBlock.getZ();

            player.sendMessage("Team 1 Spawn Set At " + x + " " + y + " " + z);

            return true;

        }

        return false;   

    }

    public boolean onCommand1(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("lobbyCreate") && sender instanceof Player) {

            Player player = (Player) sender;

            Selection selection = getWorldEdit().getSelection(player);
            Location LocA = selection.getMaximumPoint();
            Location LocB = selection.getMinimumPoint();
            World world = player.getWorld();
            CuboidSelection lobby = new CuboidSelection(world, LocA, LocB);

            return true;

        }

        return false;   

    }
    public Location lobbyLocation;
    public boolean onCommand2(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("lobbySetSpawn") && sender instanceof Player) {

            Player player = (Player) sender;

            Location lobbyLocation = player.getLocation();

            return true;

        }

        return false;   

    }


}
```

Here's the error I get

```java
Error occurred while enabling MiniGame v1.0 (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Plugin already initialized!
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.initialize(PluginClassLoader.java:122) ~[spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-b2c2c63-a3cb1bc]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.<init>(JavaPlugin.java:66) ~[spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-b2c2c63-a3cb1bc]
        at me.jobisingh.MainClass.<init>(MainClass.java:36) ~[?:?]
        at me.jobisingh.ListenerClass.<init>(ListenerClass.java:16) ~[?:?]
        at me.jobisingh.MainClass.onEnable(MainClass.java:40) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:321) ~[spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-b2c2c63-a3cb1bc]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:340) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-b2c2c63-a3cb1bc]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:405) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-b2c2c63-a3cb1bc]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.java:356) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-b2c2c63-a3cb1bc]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:316) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-b2c2c63-a3cb1bc]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.s(MinecraftServer.java:414) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-b2c2c63-a3cb1bc]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.k(MinecraftServer.java:378) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-b2c2c63-a3cb1bc]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:333) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-b2c2c63-a3cb1bc]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:263) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-b2c2c63-a3cb1bc]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:524) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-b2c2c63-a3cb1bc]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_51]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Initial initialization
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.initialize(PluginClassLoader.java:125) ~[spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-b2c2c63-a3cb1bc]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.<init>(JavaPlugin.java:66) ~[spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-b2c2c63-a3cb1bc]
        at me.jobisingh.MainClass.<init>(MainClass.java:36) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:76) ~[spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-b2c2c63-a3cb1bc]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:131) ~[spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-b2c2c63-a3cb1bc]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:329) ~[spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-b2c2c63-a3cb1bc]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:251) ~[spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-b2c2c63-a3cb1bc]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:291) ~[spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-b2c2c63-a3cb1bc]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:198) ~[spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-b2c2c63-a3cb1bc]
        ... 2 more
```

Comment: after googling your exception: https://bukkit.org/threads/plugin-already-initialized.331710/

Comment: Post the code and stack trace directly in the question respectively with code formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I checked out the link you said, The problem was pretty close to that of which was in the link. To fix it I just removed the MainClass import from my listener class and then I imported MainClass a different way.

Answer (score 0):

Error occurred while enabling MiniGame v1.0 (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Plugin already initialized!

Your plugin can't be loaded because is already loaded, I think that's problem creating duplicated registering listener or any other part of plugin.

Comment: What Can i do about that?

Comment: When i remove the   new ListenerClass(this);
                          new Game();                                                                       from the onEnable The plugin starts up but the code from the ListenerClass Does not execute